# Get value of string before a special character in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

This seems like a simple issue but I am not being able to figure this out.

I have the following string array called results:

```
21|Commercial Property Green
100|Social Services Commercial Property
5|Social Services Professional
6501|Personal Property
```

I only need the number part of the string (i.e. 21, 100, 5 & 6501 and they could be string, no need for them to be integers). How would I do that?

Let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the string in the array are of same format you could use the following

```
 for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){
  System.out.println(arr[i].substring(0,arr[i].indexOf('|')));
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the easiest one, and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You guys love regex too much....

```
int x = line.indexOf('|');
if(x==-1) 
    ... parse error
else
    return line.substring(0,x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `split()` method

```
String str = "21|Commercial Property Green Endorsement";
String[] parts = str.split("\\|");
String part1 = parts[0]; // 21
String part2 = parts[1]; // Commercial Property Green Endorsement
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression: `([^|]+)`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^|]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if(matcher.find()) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something simple like this, assuming what you pasted are each item in the array

```
public class StringSplit {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] lines = new String[]{"21|Commercial Property Green Endorsement",
      "100|Social Services Commercial Property Endorsement",
      "5|Social Services Professional Liability",
      "6501|Personal Property Liability"};
    for (String string : lines) {
      String num = string.split("\\|")[0];
      System.out.println(num);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not one more answer using the cool new Java 8 feature :)

```
String[] stringArray = new String[] {
    "21|Commercial Property Green Endorsement",
    "100|Social Services Commercial Property Endorsement",
    "5|Social Services Professional Liability",
    "6501|Personal Property Liability"
};

int[] intArray = Arrays.stream(stringArray).mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.split("\\|")[0])).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i< results.length(); i++) {
results[i].split("\\|")[0];}
```

Split() is a method defined in String class

```
    public String[] split(String regex) {
    return split(regex, 0);
}
```

Escape characters (also called escape sequences or escape codes) in general are used to signal an alternative interpretation of a series of characters. In Java, a character preceded by a backslash () is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the java compiler. 
We use \ as the escape character , else '|' would not be considered.

It splits and returns a String array as you can see in the Split() definition.

Comment: It would be beneficial for the OP if you explained the regular expression

Comment: Thank you @DavidBrossard for your valuable comments. I'll do now